# How to add contextual filter?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms, blocks, uri

I am working with books in drupal 8. I want to display a specific page("table of contenets") on the sidebar whenever any page of that     book is accessed. "table of contents" is a book page. every page of book has two id's.

- page_id
- book_id

*Page_id* is unique for every page but book id is same for all pages. I believe **contextual filter based on *book_id*** might solve my issue. but I don't know how to add contextual filter based on book id.

here are the results of `SELECT * FROM book`

[image]

I can see this "**Top level book from current node**" . I think this is helpful to do my task. can anybody explain me how can use that option.

[image]

Need tons of help.

Thank you!

Comment: The **Book** module already provides a block that displays the table of contents.  Does that not work for you?  With Contextual Filters, you could try using "Top Level Book from current node", but Book is an old module with iffy Views support.

Comment: I don't know where to find that block that displays table of contents. To be precise, I need to display two book pages on every book page url. one of them is "table of contents" .

Comment: The block that displays the table of contents can be found with all the other blocks at `/admin/structure/block`.  If you still need help, please edit your question to be more specific.  For example, how many books is "some books"?  If you only need this for a few books, and you won't be adding more, it will be faster to make some custom blocks.  Also, you said two links on each page, one of which is table of contents.  What is the other link?

Comment: @PatrickKenny this question explains what I want [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/308393/how-to-customize-table-of-contents-block-of-book-module), need help sir!